# Fit t distribution using scipy with predetermined mean and std(loc & scale)?

Tags: python, scipy

How can I fit t distribution using `scipy.stats.t.fit()` with predetermined mean and std?

The question is, I have a standardized dataset, with `mean=0` and `std=1`, I only want to get `df` of t distribution.
But when I do `scipy.stats.t.fit(data)`, it outputs `df, loc, scale`, and loc&sclae not necessarily equal to 0&1.

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the call to `.fit()`, use the arguments `floc=0` and `fscale=1` to fix these parameters.

Here's an example.  First, import `t` and generate a sample to work with:

```
In [24]: from scipy.stats import t

In [25]: np.random.seed(123)

In [26]: sample = t.rvs(3, loc=0, scale=1, size=10000)
```

Now use the `.fit()` method to fit the `t` distribution to the sample, constraining the location to 0 and the scale to 1:

```
In [27]: t.fit(sample, floc=0, fscale=1)
Out[27]: (3.1099609375000048, 0, 1)
```

There are more examples (using different distributions) in the [`fit` docstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html) and [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscipy%5D%20floc).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need